# Python/PyCharm linking source files to test files

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, shortcut

Back when I was developing in Java, I could add a comment to the top of my Java classes and eclipse would know to jump to that file when I placed my cursor on the comment and pressed F3

```
import net.java.io

//MyClassTest   
public class MyClass {

  public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
  }

}
```

As mentioned, clicking on the commented "MyClassTest" in the above code and pressing F3 would jump to a class called MyClassTest, assuming only one existed.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this with PyCharm as of yet.  I'm working on a very large project, so it can sometimes be hard to find a test file if it's not already open.  And, test classes aren't always named as simply as "MyClassTest".

Is there a similar commenting method I can use to enable quick jumping from source to test files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Navigate | Test (Ctrl-Shift-T in the default keymap). The feature uses a name-based heuristic for finding the tests of a class, and shows you a chooser popup if there are multiple candidates. It can also navigate in the opposite direction, from a test to its test subject class.

There is currently no way to control this feature by putting a special comment in the class. You're welcome to file this as a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: I'm not going to accept this because I was asking for a solution that doesn't require me to know the name of the test class.

Comment: I take that back.  Placing my cursor *inside* the class and pressing CMD+Shift+T did, in fact, show me a list of relevant test classes.

Comment: "uses a name-based heuristic" -> can you provide some details on what kind of names work and which ones don't?